# Deleting and copying files using batch file

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to copy files from one drive to another using a batch file, Which works! but we keep Changing file names on our main file which creates addition copys with diffrent names everytime its run. I dont want to delete the Copy file entirely bacause of the length of time the copy takes just to copy. I would like to Compare the 2 files and delete the files that are no longer on the main drive here is the test that im working on. Thanks for any help you can give me.

```
@echo
cls
If not exist "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Main\*.*" "Del "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Clone\*.*"
xcopy "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Main\*.*" "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Clone\*.*" /D /C /E /S /I /Y /V /H /R /F /d:01-01-1998
pause

:abort
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation. 
goto exit
```

Comment: As you explained: the copy process is lengthy - but any process to compare all the files `by content` will be equally lengthy or longer.  Can it can compare by filesize? (you said the filenames change)  Can you outline the kind of makeup of the files?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look into `robocopy`, specifically with the `/mir` switch, which mirrors (copy all new files and delete all no longer existing files) the source folder to the target.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
This does work

```
@echo
cls
robocopy /MIR "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Main" "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Clone"
pause

:abort
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation. 
goto exit
```

But I would still like to understand if anyone can or wants to take the time to correct my original question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@echo off
cls
If not exist "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Main\*.*" "Del "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Clone\*.*"
xcopy "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Main\*.*" "C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\Test Clone\*.*" /D /C /E /S /I /Y /V /H /R /F /d:01-01-1998

If %errorlevel% EQU 2 (
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation.
)
pause
```